# HTML background color for only the txt

Tags: html

I have the following line which is highlighted in yellow and red..the problem I am facing with this is the whole line gets yellow background instead of just the text..how do I take care so that only the text has the yellow background?

```
GerritMailBody += "<p style=\"color:red;background-color:yellow;\">CR Owners - </p>"
```

Comment: The idea of having a text with background usually renders itself in a way that the whole line of that said text has that background.
Other than that: Do not use `<p>`, use `<span>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the text in a span inside the p?  Then you could apply the style to that and you wouldn't have a bunch of white space with the background color applied.

```
GerritMailBody += "<p><span style='color:red;background-color:yellow;'>CR Owners - </span></p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want red background and yellow text, here is the code:

```
<p style="background:red"><font color="yellow">CR Owners - </font></p>
```

If you want only yellow text with white background:

```
<p><font color="yellow">CR Owners - </font></p>
```